power supply for small volume plasma
I need to power a small plasma source (about 1 1/2 inches internal diameter) with a single
wire like anode.  The target pressure range is up to a couple of hundred millitorr.
I have been looking at high voltage dc which seems like it might work, however I have read
there might be current striations as the pressure increases, and I need to create a uniform
and steady glow. I do not want to create an arc.
I believe that higher frequency pulsed dc might be the answer and  only need enough current to sustain the plasma when lit, and enough voltage to light it.  I think Amazing had products that might have worked but they are no longer around.   Does this sort of approach seem reasonable? Are there recommendations for a circuit design or off the shelf components that might work or come close. (The circuit also needs a current limit to prevent a runaway condition when the plasma lights.)   Suggestions would be much appreciated

Please try to give numbers for those current and voltage that you need.

You'll need to specify more details to get a useful answer. Whether you get a glow discharge or an arc depends in part on current. At high current, electrodes vaporize. Also, current strongly affects electrode sputtering. See the GE Glow Lamp Manual for more information. Starting on p. 1, it describes the various regimes in conduction, such as Townsend discharge, self-maintained discharge, negative resistance region, normal glow discharge, abnormal glow region and arc region.
Some other details needed include the gases in the mixture, electrode shape and cooling of the electrodes. You might need to explore experimentally what the parameters are. It is also feasible to have a glow discharge without direct electrode contact, such as from a RF field. This can help prevent contamination.

Thanks for the link.  I am wanting to use (or slightly modify) a cold cathode gauge for plasma operation in the 25 to 500 mtorr range. Based on normal cc performance I am thinking 3 to 4kv with maybe 50 milliamps would be enough. The caveat is that "apparently" there might be questions of plasma stability that would be improved with higher frequency. From what I've read a   ccg may pulse around 10 to 15htz.  Chemistry  exposure would be  n2  to typical semiconductor gases.  I want to use it as an oes source, so it does not need to be super bright.  Thanks again for the reference.
